# Problem loading directory level pages of website

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I just deployed my create-react-app via github pages. The site ([jasonclerk.com](https://jasonclerk.com)) loads fine when clicking through to the root domain or entering the root domain in URL address bar of browser. However if deep-linking to a directory level page (jasonclerk.com/about) or entering that directory level page in URL address bar, I'm hitting 404 error. If I use the navigation within the site, I can go to the other pages without any issue.

I did use routes (react-router-dom) in my top level component, all have been working fine in local test environment. Also, previously deployed the site via heroku and didn't have any issue with deeplinks. Deployed on ghpages now so I could add custom domain.

Any advice to fix the issue on loading directory level pages directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router` is a good example of client-side routing. You are facing this issue because the GitHub Page server has no idea you are building a client-side routing application. From the server's point of view, it does not recognize `/about`. There are 2 ways to solve your issue.

1. Use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`, the URL will end up not as pretty but since it uses hashes, you don't have to do anything special on the server-side.
2. Follow this [guide](https://reginafurness.medium.com/client-side-routing-on-github-pages-with-create-react-app-f5a393341c2) here to implement a "hacky" solution for Github Pages. Basically, you add a script in the `404.html` (i.e. the page GitHub will display when it receives 404 error), which will redirect all request to your `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew HashRouter worked brilliantly!